# Change StringWriter xml node output

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

I am using .NET Core 3.1

Is there any way of editing the xml node that StringWriter outputs?

I'd like to change the casing of "utf-8" for example. The output currently looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

My code is like below.

```
public class MyStringWriter: StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.UTF8;
}
```

My function that writes out xml

```
using (TextWriter tw= new MyStringWriter())
{
    using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(tw))
    {
        xmlDoc.WriteTo(xw);
    }
    var output = tw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `StringWriter` is not the class outputting this (directly, at least); that's `XmlWriter`. If you need control this fine-grained, I suggest just writing the XML declaration yourself to the `TextWriter` and using `XmlWriter.Create(tw, new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true })`. If this was "just an example" and you'd like to twiddle any node after the fact, I suggest changing the XML itself or doing string replacement after the fact; the `StringWriter` is still not the appropriate place to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the Xml declaration manually:

```
using (TextWriter tw= new MyStringWriter())
{
    using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(tw))
    {
        xw.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'");
        xmlDoc.WriteTo(xw);
    }
    var output = tw.ToString();
}
```